# A Linq to SQL query is very slow when using an interger variable compared to a hardcoded integer value

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, ienumerable

I have a query that takes about 10 seconds to execute.

The strange thing is that if i replace the "machineNo" paramater with a hardcoded integer (eg. 3), the query takes a split second. This is the most unusual performance issue i have encountered to date.

```
public static IEnumerable<vwJobAppointment> GetAllJobs(int machineNo)
{
    var db = new DbContext();
    IEnumerable<vwJobAppointment> list;
    list = db.vwJobAppointments.Where(a => a.ResourceId == (machineNo)).AsNoTracking().ToList();
    return list;
}
```

Query takes 10 seconds +

```
public static IEnumerable<vwJobAppointment> GetAllJobs(int machineNo)
{
    var db = new DbContext();
    IEnumerable<vwJobAppointment> list;
    list = db.vwJobAppointments.Where(a => a.ResourceId == (3)).AsNoTracking().ToList();
    return list;
}
```

This query takes under a second.

Any ideas? I'm using Entity Framework 5 with a SQL 2008 database

Comment: I think second query run faster because query plan is in cache when you run first query with machineNo variable.

Comment: Is the `3` the same value being passed in as `machineNo`? Or a different value?

Comment: Same value... so exact same dataset returned

Comment: Both queries are tested as the First query when the application starts, so shouldnt be a cache issue

Comment: "first query" isn't just up to your application - the actual database gets a say too, and it can cache horribly inappropriate plans based on parameter sniffing.

Comment: ResourceId is of type 'int' in the database

Comment: Consider giving https://hibernatingrhinos.com/products/efprof a whirl to get more insight into what is happening under the covers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF querys are translated to SQL. SQL uses query plans to optimize the query. Variables tend to make Procedures a lot slower. You can in some cases overcome this if you select the input variables in a temporary table and join this table where you would normally check against the input variable. Another benefit of the procedure is that you can force a query plan. I would suggest to :

- Create a stored procedure that takes the resource ID as input
- Try to select input variable in a temporary table and join that
- If that doesnt help force a query plan

Comment: " Variables tend to make Procedures a lot slower" - that's ... not really true; " You can in some cases overcome this if you select the input variables in a temporary table and join this table where you would normally check against the input variable." - that's also dubious; there are *some cases* where a temp table (or table variable) might help, but that's nowhere near the top of the list of things to try; " Another benefit of the procedure is that you can force a query plan." - you can do that anyway - your ability to do that is not changed

Comment: "Create a stored procedure that takes the resource ID as input" - that is the solution to some problems, but not this one; the query plan here doesn't care whether it is a stored procedure or not. 90%+ of the time I see people saying "use a sproc", it is completely unrelated to the problem.

Comment: I just suggested to create a sproc to be able to do the other things I suggested. Or is there a possibility to force a query plan from an EF select on a table?

Comment: there's middle ground between sprocs and EF-generated-SQL, is the point; you can run ad-hoc SQL through EF very easily, and with ad-hoc parameterized SQL you can do *everything* that you would have done in a sproc, including query hints

Comment: I think it's not that simple to takle this problem with no access to the database it occurs on. So take my answer just as a suggestion for uncommon things you could try easily and that did help me in the past.

Comment: Creating a Stored Procedure instead of a view has fixed my problem. The actual reason for the delay still isnt clear to me. But for now all i wanted was a solution, so thank you very much.

Comment: @NeilHobson you need to be cautious; with parameter sniffing, it is *common* that forcing a recompile (which is what you essentially did here) will temporarily "fix" it - but that can also just mean that you've caused it - for now - to use the plan that it generated for *some other value*, one that works OK enough. It can revert back **at any point**. Unless you've addressed the actual problem (which: moving to a sproc *does not do*), all you've done is given it a kick and gone back to ignoring the actual problem. This can (and will) hurt you again.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like parameter sniffing; i.e. typical parameterized plan cache problems where the query plan is generated using an *initial* example parameter value that turns out to require a very different plan than some other values. This is very common if the data is skewed - for example, some values would have 3 matches and other values would have 300,000 matches. This is typically when the `OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR ... UNKNOWN)` hint comes into play, but that requires *either* that your ORM has the ability to specify this hint, *or* for you to write the SQL by hand.

Answer (score 0):

You can optimize your where expression a little. In that case you can reassign parameter variable to local variable. In my test I have three methods:

```
// Execution time: 00:00:00.0140118
public static IEnumerable<myClass> GetAllJobs(int machineNo)
{
    var db = new DbContext();
    IEnumerable<myClass> list;
    list = db.vwJobAppointments.Where(a => a.ResourceId == (machineNo)).ToList();
    return list;
}

// Execution time: 00:00:00.0019991
public static IEnumerable<myClass> GetAllJobs2(int machineNo)
{
    var db = new DbContext();
    IEnumerable<myClass> list;
    list = db.vwJobAppointments.Where(a => a.ResourceId == 55).ToList();
    return list;
}

// Execution time: 00:00:00.0010013
public static IEnumerable<myClass> GetAllJobs3(int machineNo)
{
    int machineNo2 = machineNo;
    var db = new DbContext();
    IEnumerable<myClass> list;
    list = db.vwJobAppointments.Where(a => a.ResourceId == (machineNo2)).ToList();
    return list;
}
```